# How many of Naruto Shippuden episodes are dubbed?

Tags: naruto

I would like to know how many episodes of Naruto Shippuden are dubbed because I've only seen about 388 in all my anime streaming websites?

Answer (score 7):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto:_Shippuden_episodes#DVD_releases), the number of dubbed episodes from *Naruto Shippudden* stands at 402 episodes. The last DVD was released on June 27, 2017, which covered episodes 389-402.

The next release of dubbed DVD is on 10th October 2017,  which will cover episodes 403-416.